# How do I get bash's "find -rename" command to print what it's going to do without doing it?

Tags: bash

When I do a mass rename operation, I will first do

```sh
for i in $(ls); do
  echo $i $i.new_extension
done
```

and then I will check everything makes sense and replace `echo` with `mv` or `cp` and re-run the command.

How do I do the same with `find -rename`?

Comment: Use -exec echo '{}' \; -exec echo '{}'.new_extension \;

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` with `echo`, then remove the `echo`, for example:

```
find . -name 'foo*' -exec echo "mv {} {}.bak" \;

# if OK, repeat without the echo:
find . -name 'foo*' -exec mv {} {}.bak \;
```

Alternatively, use `find` with `rename --dry-run`, then remove the `--dry-run`:

```
find . -name 'foo*' -exec rename --dry-run 's/foo/bar/' {} \;

# If OK, repeat without --dry-run:
find . -name 'foo*' -exec rename 's/foo/bar/' {} \;
```

If you can use a glob instead of `find`, use just `rename --dry-run` alone, then remove the `--dry-run`:

```
rename --dry-run 's/foo/bar/' foo*

# If OK, repeat without --dry-run:
rename 's/foo/bar/' foo*
```

Note that `rename` can be installed easily, for example with `conda`:

```
conda install rename
```

**SEE ALSO:**
`rename` manual (very helpful):

```
rename --man
```

For example:

```
-n, --dry-run, --just-print
    Show how the files would be renamed, but don't actually do anything.
```